# Resources for Indonesian/Austronesian etymology

Tags: etymology, resource-request, online-resources, austronesian

I'm looking for online resources for Austronesian languages etymology.

KBBI doesn't provide any etymology, which is astonishing for such a notable and official dictionary.
The only source I've found so far is Wiktionary, and it's not satisfactory.
I'm sure I'm not the only one to search for this.

Comment: You might find [*The Austronesian Comparative Dictionary*](https://www.trussel2.com/ACD/) interesting (for Indonesian, you'll have to look under varieties of Malay).